# How do I extract the brand name from a list of products from a website?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have this so far:

```
lst = ["Tommy", "Tommy Hilfiger", "Tommy Jeans", "Hugo", "Hugo Boss", "Boss", "HUGO", "BOSS", "Lacoste", "lacoste",
       "Adidas",
       "adidas", "Armani", "North", "Paul", "Smith", "Vivienne Westwood", "Levis", "Kent", "Nike", "Calvin Klein",
       "Calvin",
       "Pretty Green"]

 title_div = soup.find_all(class_='product-name')
 for container5 in title_div:
   container_text = container5.text.split(' ')
   for string in container_text:
     if string in lst:
       print(string)
```

This returns just the first name: for example, just "Tommy" from "Tommy Hilfiger" or "Pretty" when I would like to return "Pretty Green".

Any suggestions on how to make this work?

****The following code is whats stored in container_text

```
container_text =

['HUGO', 'Dolive', 'T', 'Shirt', 'Blue']
['Tommy', 'Hilfiger', 'Lounge', 'Logo', 'Flag', 'T', 'Shirt', 'White']
['BOSS', 'Multi', 'Colour', 'Triple', 'Pack', 'T', 'Shirts']
['BOSS', 'Triple', 'Pack', 'Crew', 'Neck', 'T', 'Shirts']
['EA7', 'Emporio', 'Armani', 'Crew', 'Neck', 'Logo', 'T', 'Shirt', 'Grey']
['PS', 'By', 'Paul', 'Smith', 'Regular', 'Fit', 'T', 'Shirt', 'Blue']
['The', 'North', 'Face', 'Fine', 'Alpine', '2', 'T', 'Shirt', 'Khaki']
['Vivienne', 'Westwood', 'Orb', 'Logo', 'T', 'Shirt', 'Grey']
['Levis', 'Logo', 'Crew', 'Neck', 'T', 'Shirt', 'White']
['Nike', 'Futura', 'Icon', 'T', 'Shirt', 'White']
['Calvin', 'Klein', 'Jeans', 'Tape', 'T', 'Shirt', 'White']
['Tommy', 'Hilfiger', 'Lounge', 'Logo', 'Flag', 'T', 'Shirt', 'Green']
['Tommy', 'Hilfiger', 'Logo', 'T', 'Shirt', 'Navy']
['adidas', 'Originals', '3', 'Stripe', 'T', 'Shirt', 'Blue']
['Nike', 'Futura', 'Icon', 'T', 'Shirt', 'Black']
['Tommy', 'Hilfiger', 'Flag', 'T', 'Shirt', 'Khaki']
['BOSS', 'Tblurry', '5', 'T', 'Shirt', 'Black']
['Tommy', 'Hilfiger', 'Flag', 'T', 'Shirt', 'Grey']
['Lacoste', 'Crew', 'Neck', 'T', 'Shirt', 'Blue']
['Tommy', 'Hilfiger', 'Logo', 'T', 'Shirt', 'Navy']
['Lacoste', 'Crew', 'Neck', 'T', 'Shirt', 'Blue']
['Pretty', 'Green', 'X', 'Umbro', 'Ringer', 'T', 'Shirt', 'Blue']
['Armani', 'Exchange', 'Crew', 'Neck', 'Logo', 'T', 'Shirt', 'White']
['The', 'North', 'Face', 'Logo', 'T', 'Shirt', 'Blue']
['HUGO', 'Dolive', 'Logo', 'T', 'Shirt', 'Black']
['Tommy', 'Hilfiger', 'Loungewear', 'Taped', 'T', 'Shirt', 'Navy']
['Tommy', 'Hilfiger', 'Loungewear', 'Logo', 'T', 'Shirt', 'White']
['Tommy', 'Hilfiger', 'Loungewear', 'Icon', 'T', 'Shirt', 'Navy']
['Tommy', 'Hilfiger', 'Loungewear', 'Icon', 'T', 'Shirt', 'White']
['Tommy', 'Hilfiger', 'Loungewear', 'Round', 'Neck', 'T', 'Shirt', 'Grey']
['Kent', 'And', 'Curwen', 'Rose', 'Patch', 'Icon', 'T', 'Shirt', 'Black']
['HUGO', 'Dolive', 'Crew', 'Neck', 'T', 'Shirt', 'Black']
['HUGO', 'Dolive', 'Crew', 'Neck', 'T', 'Shirt', 'White']
['HUGO', 'Dolive', 'Crew', 'Neck', 'T', 'Shirt', 'White']
['Tommy', 'Hilfiger', 'Lounge', 'Logo', 'Flag', 'T', 'Shirt', 'Navy']
['Tommy', 'Hilfiger', 'Lounge', 'Logo', 'Flag', 'T', 'Shirt', 'White']
['Tommy', 'Hilfiger', 'Lounge', 'Logo', 'Flag', 'T', 'Shirt', 'Grey']
['Calvin', 'Klein', 'Crew', 'Neck', 'Lounge', 'T', 'Shirt', 'White']
['Tommy', 'Hilfiger', 'Loungewear', '3', 'Pack', 'T', 'Shirts', 'White']
['Calvin', 'Klein', 'Logo', 'T', 'Shirt', 'Black']
['Tommy', 'Hilfiger', 'Lounge', '3', 'Pack', 'V', 'Neck', 'T', 'Shirts', 'White']
['Calvin', 'Klein', 'Short', 'Sleeved', 'T', 'Shirt', 'White']
['Tommy', 'Hilfiger', 'Lounge', '3', 'Pack', 'V', 'Neck', 'T', 'Shirts']
['Calvin', 'Klein', 'Short', 'Sleeved', 'T', 'Shirt', 'Black']
['Calvin', 'Klein', 'Crew', 'Neck', 'Logo', 'T', 'Shirt', 'Grey']
['Calvin', 'Klein', 'Lounge', 'Logo', 'T', 'Shirt', 'White']
['Tommy', 'Hilfiger', 'Core', 'Slim', 'T', 'Shirt', 'Grey']
['Tommy', 'Hilfiger', 'Core', 'Slim', 'Fit', 'T', 'Shirt', 'White']
['Tommy', 'Hilfiger', 'Core', 'Slim', 'T', 'Shirt', 'Navy']
['Tommy', 'Hilfiger', 'Core', 'Slim', 'T', 'Shirt', 'Black']
['BOSS', 'TChup', 'T', 'Shirt', 'Navy']
['BOSS', 'Tales', 'Logo', 'T', 'Shirt', 'Black']
['Calvin', 'Klein', 'Jeans', 'Institutional', 'T', 'Shirt', 'White']
['Calvin', 'Klein', 'Jeans', 'Institutional', 'T', 'Shirt', 'Black']
['BOSS', 'Tales', 'T', 'Shirt', 'White']
```

There is normally a total of 65 rows

Comment: Can you edit your question and add a representative sample of `container_text`?

Comment: @jack fleeting I have added container text to question

Comment: Are there no commas or anything separating the elements in `container_text`?

Comment: No, I think they need to be separated

Comment: I see; in that case, can you add to your question a small (!) representative part of `container5.text`?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are parsing the HTML fine, I think you should just check for subsets like so:

```
lst = ["Tommy", "Tommy Hilfiger", "Tommy Jeans", "Hugo", "Hugo Boss", "Boss", "HUGO", "BOSS", "Lacoste", "lacoste",
       "Adidas",
       "adidas", "Armani", "North", "Paul", "Smith", "Vivienne Westwood", "Levis", "Kent", "Nike", "Calvin Klein",
       "Calvin",
       "Pretty Green"]

mystring = "Tommy"
for x in lst:
    if set(mystring).issubset(x):
        print(x,mystring)
#Tommy Tommy
#Tommy Hilfiger Tommy
#Tommy Jeans Tommy
```

Answer (score 0):

### Inverting the search

Instead of looking if word from your container.text object is in the list of brands, it is better to see if any of the brands is in your text.

```py
brand_names = ["Tommy", "Tommy Hilfiger", "Tommy Jeans", "Hugo", "Hugo Boss", "Boss", "HUGO", "BOSS", "Lacoste", "lacoste",
       "Adidas",
       "adidas", "Armani", "North", "Paul", "Smith", "Vivienne Westwood", "Levis", "Kent", "Nike", "Calvin Klein",
       "Calvin",
       "Pretty Green"]

title_div = soup.find_all(class_='product-name')
for container5 in title_div:
    for brand in brand_names:
        if brand in container5.text:
            print(brand)
```

### Use informative names

As a side-note, try to use more informative names for your variables. For example, I replaced `lst` with `brand_names`, as it makes it much clearer to know what is going on.

### Separate logic from printing

It's always a good principle to separate methods that need user interaction from the code that is actually performing the logic. This makes it easier to reuse your code in other situations or to change some things that are only related to the output.

In this case it might look like:

```py
def find_brands(title_div, brands):
    for container5 in title_div:
        for brand in brand_names:
            if brand in container5.text:
                yield brand # Generator

def print_matches(matches):
    if len(matches)==0:
        print('Other')

    for match in matches:
        print(match)

def main():
    # Add code for creating soup in front of this.
    title_div = soup.find_all(class_='product-name')
    matched_brands=list(find_brands(title_div, brand_names))
    print_matches(matched_brands)
```

Note that I used a [generator](https://www.guru99.com/python-yield-return-generator.html) here. For now you can just think about is as returning a one-time list.

Then you can just call the main method.

Comment: This is really close, I want it so that if one line in the list(container5) does not contain any of the keywords in the brand_names list. I would like it to output "None"

Comment: @jeffgrills Before I add that, what do you want to happen if multiple brands match?

Comment: If it does just print "other". Thank You.

Comment: @jeffgrills I've added the new version, with some extra informationo about seperating logic and printing